# mplayer is not playing for yuv

Tags: linux

I am trying to play yuv file in mplayer, it working fine till yesterday. But now i tried to play,its not working. It is trying to playback,i didnt see a visualization. While it's working,i didnt got this

> Could not find matching colorspace - retrying with -vf scale...
>
> Opening video filter: [scale]
>
> Movie-Aspect is undefined - no prescaling applied.

as now i am getting.Can any body tell me what will be the reason? I am using this command

> mplayer -demuxer rawvideo -rawvideo w=176:h=144:format=i420 a.yuv -loop 0

Answer (score 1):

[Play](http://my.opera.com/elephs/blog/show.dml/1555740) the `*.yuv` file in a [manner](http://gettinginsidelinux.blogspot.in/2009/05/play-yuv-files-under-linux.html). I am not too sure that this will run but try this.
In the command `w & h` should be exactly mention as it is in `*.yuv` file.

```
 mplayer a.yuv -demuxer rawvideo -rawvideo w=352:h=288
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a yuv 4:2:0 file, with format:i420 it gives the same error. it works with "mplayer -demuxer rawvideo -rawvideo w=352:h=288:format=yv12 a.yuv". you may try with format "yv12, yuy2, y8", if you are not sure the video colorspace.